# Is a license key for Windows 7 Professional valid for different languages?

Tags: windows-7, language

I bought a laptop that comes with a German Windows 7 professional pre-installed.

Is it possible to reinstall the OS in English using the same license key? I do not want to have a half-translated version, so I thought reinstalling it before I install anything else on the computer might be the easiest way.

Is the license key language-specific or not?

Answer (score 5):

No it is not  language specific and it is possible to choose a language during install

Answer (score 1):

You can choose your language, that's not a problem. **But** the key is aimed to work with a localized installation disc. I mean, your serial is for a specific version (Pro/Home/etc.) and a "country".

My french "Windows XP édition familiale" key can't work with the english "Windows XP Home edition" CD, although I can use the english language.

*edit* : as @omnibrain mentioned, it might be possible to install Win7 with an "english" DVD and a "german" key (he did). Consider my contribution as a warning and enlightenment :)

Comment: Nice bit of extra info +1

Comment: He asked for Windows 7. Things changed. I successfully installed english Win 7 pro with "german" key. Or otherwise.

Comment: It’s because XP was on a CD, so the CDs were single-language, but 7 is on a DVD, so there is enough room to put all the language files.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the English language pack via Windows Updates.

Edit: No you can't in Professional edition. Only in Windows Enterprise and Ultimate editions.

Answer (score 0):

it's an old question, but anyway, for future readers. There is [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/en/index.html):

> Vistalizator overrides the limit of one MUI language on non-Ultimate Windows editions.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Works in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows Vista/Windows 7 Change
> - Windows display language in less than 5 minutes! (Express installation
>   mode)
> - Uses official Microsoft Windows language packs
> - You can install all 36 MUI languages and switch between them easily
> - You can install 55 Windows Vista LIP languages on top of specific MUI languages You can install 59 Windows 7 LIP languages on top of specific MUI languages
> - Compatible with Vista Service Pack 1/2 and Windows 7 Service Pack 1
> - User Account Control (UAC) compliant - prompts for administrative
>   privileges
> - Windows Speech Recognition works with all supported
>   languages: Chinese, English, French, German, Japanese and Spanish
> - Languages can be installed either in Internal or in Express mode, see
>   [details](http://www.froggie.sk/en/details.html)